# Managing objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am using javascript to manage an input object defined as below :

```
Obj= {first:['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'], second:[1,2,4,5,2,7,5,6,3,2,7]} 

a -> 1,2,3,4   
b -> 2,7,5 
c ->  6,3,2,7
```

I want to build an output object like that :

```
output_obj = {a: [1,2,3,4],  b: [2,7,5],  c:[6,3,2,7]}
```

could someone help?

Comment: `first:[a,a,a,a, b,b,b, c,c,c,c]` is an invalid expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to loop the `first` and get to corresponding value from `second`.

Below is JS code (ES6) to solve it

```js
let data = {first:['a','a','a','a', 'b','b','b','c','c','c','c'], second:[1,2,4,5, 2,7,5  , 6,3,2,7]} 

let out = {};

data.first.forEach((key, index) => {
  out[key] = out[key] || [];
  out[key].push(data.second[index]);
})

console.log(out)
```